# How to create a Speech bubble in cocoa-Touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

How can I create a speech-bubble like context menu like in the Safari-Browser on the iPhone/iPad.

I would like to create a kind of context help.

Thanks in advance,

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "speech-bubble like context menu like in the Safari-Browser" is a UIPopoverController. It is only available on iPad. See

- [Using Popovers to Display Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH3-SW7)

A UIActionSheet can also be shown as popover style with `-showFromBarButtonItem:animated:` or `-showFromRect:inView:animated:` on the iPad.